# Error when building castalia : Call of an overloaded function is ambiguous

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have imprted castalia 3.3 to omnet++4.6. But I have got this error when building it with make so CastaliaBin is not constructed and I can not use castalia project.

**src/wirelessChannel/traceChannel/TraceChannel.cc:35:33: error: call of overloaded ‘open(cPar&)’ is ambiguous**

**traceFile.open(par("traceFile"));**

I am not an expert in C++, I couldn't fix it

This is the error localistion and then the open() function

```
ofstream & DebugInfoWriter::getStream(void)
{
    if (!theFile.is_open())
        theFile.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::app);
    theFile.setf(ios::left);

    return theFile;
}

void
  open(const char* __s,
   ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc)
  {
if (!_M_filebuf.open(__s, __mode | ios_base::out))
  this->setstate(ios_base::failbit);
else

  this->clear();
  }
```

Comment: thats why you should never use "using namespace std". also variable stating with "__" are a no-no

Comment: This is not a code I wrote, this is imported code from castalia project (with many hierarchy folders inside) so I am not sure if I should make a changement in it

Comment: looked at the source of that "castalia", they have "using namespace std" in each of their headers and put all their stuff into the global namespace. that code is not fit for integration into any other project.

Comment: Can you tell me plz how can I do that ? There is four layers in the hierarchy and with each one there is other layers that contains folders with their headers.

Comment: This is not the code that contains the error.  The error is with the command `traceFile.open(par("traceFile"));` not with the function `open`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question also exists in the Castalia forum (Google Group).

The error appeared when newer versions of the GCC compiler were used in Ubuntu. Don't forget, Castalia 3.3 is already old (released 2013).
A simple casting solves the problem.

```
traceFile.open((const char *)par("traceFile"));
```

But you do not need to change the code. Instead, just **get the latest code** from the Castalia Github repository. It contains this fix plus other minor fixes.

Always use the latest version from the [Castalia Github repository](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia).

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helps !

Comment: since that seems to fix the issue, i'll remove my answer, which would be way more effort than this.

Comment: @Hana if this was the answer you wanted, apart from upvoting, also accept it (use the grey tick below the votes)